# Collapse and Expand

Tags: iphone, uiview

[image: At Below there is 2 buttons on the image arrow up and arrow down]

How to expand and collapse the view to just show the mini and max points under ratings[1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/TBmXN.png)

Comment: What have you already tried?

Comment: i have not tried... i m confused how to start..is it collapse the view ?